# where can I find store-level cost data for retail Chains like Walmart, QFC, Target, Kmart, etc?

Tags: data, micro-data, retail-economics

I wanna do some empirical analysis of the retail chains. Where can I find store-level cost data (such as operating cost, etc.) for retail Chains like Walmart, QFC, Target, Kmart, etc? Thanks!

Comment: I would be surprised if any retail chain publishes cost data at the level of individual stores.  They probably collect such data, for internal management purposes, but are likely to treat it as commercially confidential.

Comment: @AdamBailey I see. Thanks!